# gmail api in oauth 2.0: use javascript to request authentication code from google server

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth

### Goal

I am trying to implement a **server-side authentication**.
I want to request **authentication code** using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) on my website, and then pass the [auth](/questions/tagged/auth) code back to my server. Then my server can use this code to exchange for refresh token, and access token.

### What I have tried

I followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js), and registered my **Web application** for client ID. It's working perfectly fine, but this is only for client-side authentication, and it returns a access token directly. Then I registered **server account** for another client ID, and replace the old one with the new one. I was expecting it returned authentication code, but it returned error in the Web console.

### Error message

Load denied by [X-Frame-Options](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=756588813409-8rppjgbk77a5h8ogtqm5kgaqn68ke2rq.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.readonly&immediate=true&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay401363844&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000&response_type=token&state=279170064%7C0.2320593305&authuser=0) does not permit cross-origin framing.

### Question

1. Did I use the code in a wrong way, or my registration process might cause the problem?
2. In this website,
   there's no mention of any build-in function for getting the authentication code. Do I have to implement it from a very basic level?